# Getting parsing error in xml

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

In my xml file i'm getting "error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)".  Is there any fixes that can be done for this?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="none" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen>

<WebView android:id="@+id/webview1"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `"` at the end of the first tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

You're missing the "

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="none"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```